# NSNotification, how to handle if event is not registered

Tags: objective-c, ios

If I call an NSNotification and I have not registered to receive the event what will happen? Will I get an runtime exception? If yes, how do I handle it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean posting a notification, nothing. Posting a notification does not require a listener.